# Using php exception is still returning exception error page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, exception

I have the following controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use App\WebPackage;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;


class WebProcessController extends Controller
{


    public function sendPayment(Request $request)
    {

       if ($request->ptitle && $request->pricetotal ){

           try {
               $product = WebPackage::findOrFail($request->ptitle);
           }
           catch (NotFoundHttpException $exception){
               die();
           }
           return $product;

       }
```

Just for trying i have send a $request->ptitle with value id not in WebPackage Model.

As i know when there is error exception showing , the die() function should be work.
But still error page showing :

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

2/2
NotFoundHttpException in Handler.php line 113:
No query results for model [App\WebPackage] 20
```

Is there any thing wrong i did when using 'try' and 'catch' ?

Comment: findOrFail works with id. you should use where condition

Comment: @CavidKərimov Use i know that , the value inserted is integer

Comment: This is not found exception. There is not any row in Webpackage and that is why it throws you NotFoundException

Comment: @CavidKərimov I know , maybe you did not understand my question , i am not talking about why i cannot find any rows in DB i know that if i pass id 20 to findOrFail method is will return error .
Focus on my code catch (NotFoundHttpException $exception){
               die();
           }
This mean error should not showing at all for user , just die the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are catching invalid exception type. `findOrFail` throws `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException` if no record is found and you are catching here `NotFoundHttpException` and this is completely different exception.

In addition you should consider handling exceptions in `Handler` or set `APP_DEBUG` to `false` in `.env` file if you just want to hide errors from users.